# SymPy simplify relational (inequality) expression

Tags: python, sympy

Why doesn't the following *simplification* work, or how could it be fixed:

```
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> y = Symbol('y', real=True)
>>> simplify(x - 1 < y - 1)
x - 1 < y - 1
```

But this works:

```
>>> simplify(x - 1 - (y - 1) < 0)
x - y < 0
```

Can somehow the first expression be simplified to `x < y`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [solve for `x`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html):

```
import sympy as sy
x, y = sy.symbols('x,y', real=True)
print(sy.solve(x - 1 < y - 1, x))
```

yields

```
x < y
```

---

```
x, y, z = sy.symbols('x,y,z', real=True)
print(sy.solve(x - 1 < y*z - 1, x))
```

yields

```
x < y*z
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit how this works? If I add another variable, i.e., `x - 1 < y*z - 1` it stops working. Thanks.

Comment: `sy.solve(x - 1 < y*z - 1, x)` solves for `x` in the inequality `x - 1 < y*z - 1` and returns `x < y*z`. Is that not what you get?

Comment: this example works, but something more complicated fails, also with `real=True`: `x,y = sy.symbols('x,y', positive=True);print(sy.solve(x*x*y < x + 1, x))`