# How to rearrange sympy expressions containing a relational operator

Tags: python, sympy

I have expressions containing a relational operator, symbols, and constants. I'd like to rearrange the expressions so that (to the extent possible) all the constant terms are on one side of the relational operator, and the remaining terms on the other side.  For example, I'd like to rearrange:

x - 5 > y - z

to:

x - y + z > 5

Is there an existing sympy method for doing this?  If not, where should I start in extending sympy?

Comment: I don't believe it is a duplicate.  Calling simplify on my example expression does nothing,  The answer given on your question is to solve for a variable.  The equivalent in my case is to solve for all the constant terms on one side of the relational operator, and to simplify them by combining all the constants.  I don't know how to do this in sympy.

Comment: OK - I haven't flagged it because I wasn't sure (thanks for the response) and am currently on a machine where I can't install Sympy.  I'll have a look on my machine that does have it later if you don't get an answer in the meantime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat surprisingly, I couldn't find a way to do this "out of the box".  You can use the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825581/sympy-simplify-relational-inequality-expression) to make any one variable the sole subject of the left hand side (LHS) of the inequality but I can't seem to make the constant term the subject.

So, I wrote my own version and reproduce it below.  I've tested it on the example given and a couple of other examples.  It tries to make the right hand side (RHS) consist of either zero or only constant terms based on an optional parameter.  There may well be corner cases where it fails - use / modify with caution.

#### Code:

```
import sympy
from sympy.core.relational import Relational

mult_by_minus_one_map = {
    None: '==',
    '==': '==',
    'eq': '==',
    '!=': '!=',
    '<>': '!=',
    'ne': '!=',
    '>=': '<=',
    'ge': '<=',
    '<=': '>=',
    'le': '>=',
    '>': '<',
    'gt': '<',
    '<': '>',
    'lt': '>',
}

def move_inequality_constants(ineq, zero_on_right=False):
    l = ineq.lhs
    r = ineq.rhs
    op = ineq.rel_op
    all_on_left = l - r
    if zero_on_right:
        return Relational(all_on_left, sympy.sympify(0), op)
    else:
        coeff_dict = all_on_left.as_coefficients_dict()
        var_types = coeff_dict.keys()
        new_rhs = sympy.sympify(0)
        for s in var_types:
            if s == 1:
                all_on_left = all_on_left - coeff_dict[s]
                new_rhs = new_rhs - coeff_dict[s]
        if new_rhs < 0:
            all_on_left = all_on_left * -1
            new_rhs = new_rhs * -1
            op = mult_by_minus_one_map[op]
        return Relational(all_on_left,new_rhs,op)

# test code to demo function below    
from sympy.abc import x,y,z

test_ineqs = [ x - 5 > y - z,
               x**2 + x - 5 > y + x**2 - z,
               x + 5 > y - z,
               x**3 + y**2 >= x + 5*y - z - 15]

for k in test_ineqs:
    print('Re-arranging '+ str(k))
    kn = move_inequality_constants(k)
    print('Gives '+str(kn))
    print('Or equivalently ' + str(move_inequality_constants(k, True)))
    print('====')
```

#### Output:

```
Re-arranging x - 5 > y - z
Gives x - y + z > 5
Or equivalently x - y + z - 5 > 0
====
Re-arranging x**2 + x - 5 > x**2 + y - z
Gives x - y + z > 5
Or equivalently x - y + z - 5 > 0
====
Re-arranging x + 5 > y - z
Gives -x + y - z < 5
Or equivalently x - y + z + 5 > 0
====
Re-arranging x**3 + y**2 >= x + 5*y - z - 15
Gives -x**3 + x - y**2 + 5*y - z <= 15
Or equivalently x**3 - x + y**2 - 5*y + z + 15 >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks Richard; does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The omission of this from the `canonical` method was probably an oversight.

Perhaps the following would work for your `else` clause

```
r, l = (ineq.lhs - ineq.rhs).as_coeff_Add()
if r < 0:
    l, r = -r, -l
return Relational(l, r, ineq.rel_op).canonical
```

One might imagine that canonical would remove common factors, too, so `2x<4y` would become `x<2*y`. SymPy would be open to a pull request implementing such changes.